# copying lines from one file to another in python

Tags: python, lines, copying

Okay so my class assignment is to write the code to copy each line from one text file to a new text file. I feel like I've beaten my head against the wall too much and just can't see what I'm looking at anymore.

Here is what I have:

```
source_file = open('data1.txt', 'r')
line = numbers_file.readline()
destination_file = open('data2.txt', 'w')
source_file.seek(0)
for line in source_file:
    destination_file.writelines(line)
source_file.close()
destination_file.close()
```

Comment: `destination_file.writelines(line)` => `destination_file.write(line)`

Comment: or `destination_file.writelines(source_file)` without a loop

Comment: What is `numbers_file`? You never define it, and you don't use the value purportedly read from it.

Comment: You should be using a `with` statement instead of closing the files manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# opens original file
file1 = open("data1.txt" , "r")
# opens new file
file2 = open("data2.txt" , "w")
#for each line in old file
for line in file1:
#write that line to the new file
    file2.write(line)
#close file 1
file1.close()
#close file2
file2.clsoe()
```